# Print raw hex with GDB

Tags: c, debugging, memory, arm, gdb

When I print with GDB like

```
x/10x $r1
```

Or

```
x/10bx $r1
```

I got

```
0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd 0xee
```

How can I print that like

```
aabbccddee....
```